# peak Memory in AIR application in Flex 3

Tags: apache-flex, air, flex3, adobe, flexbuilder

I developed a AIR application in which many module use and when i load and unload module in my application that time every 4 to 5 MB system memory use and then me logout memory not release.

Comment: There is a critical bug in FP 11.* and AIR 3.*, which should be (according to their words) fixed in next releases (FP 11.3 & AIR 3.3) https://bugbase.adobe.com/index.cfm?event=bug&id=3071138 *MAYBE* this is it

Answer (score 2):

See an earlier response of mine to this - I point out various things that must be done to effectively manage the memory/performance of an application. Nothing is ever released unless it's reference count is **zero.**

[Is it possible to trace references between objects in Flash, in the same way as the Flash Builder profiler?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10200736/is-it-possible-to-trace-references-between-objects-in-flash-in-the-same-way-as/10201771#10201771)

Comment: when i load a module that time i delete Reference on its Parent document in every module..

Comment: That's not enough especially if you "share data" between the two. For instance: Application has a model - with an ArrayCollection of data. Module A - accesses this model and holds a var reference (data type: Element). Trying to unload module doesn't work because it has a reference count of at least one because it has a variable tied to the main application. In this case, during deconstruction - var element must be declared null (this removes the pointer).

Comment: The next cycle of fun, once you can get the live count to zero, is then looking at the loitering count - items that were dereferenced but not removed - aka memory leak.